# Adding JScrollPane in Netbeans visual editor

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have designed a window using Netbean's visual editor. Now, I have a JTextField, which I want to add using a Scroll bar. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not add Scollbar to a TextField.TextField is meant for inputting small entries from the user like name,age,roll number,etc.The best component to input large sized texts ,like comments, from user is JTextArea.So You must add JTextArea instead of JTextField.

After adding JTextArea to the JFrame,you can write few lines of code:-

```
JScrollPane jsc=new JScrollPane();
jsc.add(jta);
```

where 'jta' is the name of your JTextArea which your Netbeans have generated for you.

(Now ,when you add text greater than the limit size of text Area ,the scrollbars will appear. 
If you want the scrollbars appear permanently,then,the JScrollPane has two properties: horizontalScrollBarPolicy and verticalScrollBarPolicy. Set this two properties to ALWAYS and you will see the Scroll bars always irrespective the size of text in JTextArea.)

Here is the complete code to demonstrate you  what you can do:-

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

class TextAreaDemo
{
JTextArea jta;
TextAreaDemo()
{
JFrame jfrm=new JFrame("Text Area");
jfrm.setSize(200,300);
jfrm.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

jta=new JTextArea("Type Here");

//You can use this line to wrap that text when it extends on right side.
//jtxt.setLineWrap(true);


JScrollPane jscrp=new JScrollPane(jta);
jscrp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180,100));
jscrp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);


jfrm.add(jscrp);
jfrm.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String args[])
{
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){new TextAreaDemo();}});
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JTextArea and put this into a JScrollPane. If you are using the visual editor it will be done by default (dropping the TextArea into your Window). The JScrollPane has two properties: horizontalScrollBarPolicy and verticalScrollBarPolicy. Set this two properties to ALWAYS and you will see the Scroll bars.